# django LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL not working behind nginx ssl

Tags: django, ssl, nginx

The rest of the site is working, but the redirect after login is

```
http ://127.0.0.1:8443/after_login
```

not the expected

```
https://127.0.0.1:8443/after_login
```

which causes an nginx error:

400 Bad Request
The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port

How do I force the redirect link to get constructed correctly?

Environment info:

django 1.4.1

settings.py

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy('after_login')
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTOCOL', 'https')
```

Comment: Your Nginx config (with listen directive) ?

Comment: yes.  If I login in, then paste a valid link into my browser I can navigate the site.

Answer (score 1):

It was happening to me until I added `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme` to nginx's configuration:

```
location / {
  proxy_pass http://unix:/path/to/your/gunicorn_socket;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```